# Owl carousel does not work unless I refresh the page

Tags: javascript

Hello my problem with this library that does not load me on the first page, instead if I "refresh" if it loads, and the internet explorer does not work for me. someone has happened something similar. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I put a link and a capture of the error. THANK YOU https://ccc.es/empresa/ https://ibb.co/3fXLPyH

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ccc.es/wp-content/themes/norebro/assets/js/libs/owl.carousel.min.js?ver=5.4.2'></script>
```

Comment: `carousel.owlCarousel` is not a function.

Comment: Please add content of main.js file

Comment: hello@IvanBarayev, if i show you the main, thanks for the interest https://gist.github.com/ervanecarreno/991ec24d420c231c5c9001942feecb76

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible solution from another colleague who passed by here I copy it, I don't know if this solution can be improved, but it works for me for now

```js
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<!--DO NOT ENTER ANY EXTERNAL LINK IN BETWEEN-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
    });
});
</script>`
```